# Problems with Latex and fancyhdr

Tags: latex

I hope also Latex questions are welcome here on Stackoverflow since it's not really programming related.

I have a problem in defining the correct style for the header using the `fancyhdr` package. What I'd like to achieve is to have

- On odd pages on the left side the following text "My paper title"
- On even pages on the right side the text "Firstname Surname"

(Replaced with the correct text of course).

At the moment I have the following "test" Latex document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,T2A,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[pdfborder=0 0 0]{hyperref}



%define the header
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf[ROH,LEH]{Firstname Surname}
\fancyhf[REH,LOH]{\bfseries My paper title}

\begin{document}

\title{My title \\}
\author{\small{Firstname Surname}}
\date{June 9, 2009}

\maketitle


\section{Introduction}
blablabla asdfasdf asdf ads fad sf

adsfadsf a fdasfd asfd 

\subsection{This is a subsection}
Some text\ldots

\pagebreak

some further text

\pagebreak

some additional text

% Stop your text
\end{document}
```

I tried different variations of this part

```
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf[ROH,LEH]{Firstname Surname}
\fancyhf[REH,LOH]{\bfseries My paper title}
```

but I can't make it work. At the moment the text is printed on each page, odd and even. I also found [this wiki article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Page_Styles) which describes the different meanings of "ROH" etc... and it's also clear, but for some reason it doesn't work for me. I must make some silly mistake which I can't get right now...

Thx for any help!

**//Edit:**

Tex distribution: gwTeX
OS: Mac OS X 10.5.8

Comment: The various TeX distributions have discrepancies (much like browsers and CSS). Which TeX system and OS are you using?

Comment: I updated the details on my post. Thx for the info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,T2A,oneside]{article}` specifies `oneside` - that is one sided article - so all headers would get printed on all pages by fancyhdr. Change that to `twoside`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,T2A,twoside]{article}
```

See [this article](http://www-solar.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~robertc/latex/Latex.html) for information on how you might have to change page borders when using this option.

Comment: Just another question. Do you maybe have some links or know how to change the default formatting/alignment of section titles defined with `\section{some section title}`? That would be great.

Comment: Found something that seems to work: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=secthead

Answer (score 0):

Another problem I encountered, which isn't directly related to `fancyhdr`, but may still be of interest is how to modify the formatting of section headers.

These two links helped me a lot:

- TeX FAQ entry: [The style of section headings](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-secthead)
- http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_section/0.html