# Latex: avoid that page text stretches over whole page with "twoside" option

Tags: latex

I recently had a problem when writing a Latex document which I [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288084/problems-with-latex-and-fancyhdr). The solution of adding the "twoside" option worked fine for me, except that when I have a page, say the conclusion, where I have just two paragraphs, so maybe half of the page filled and I then add a "\pagebreak" for having the "reference" part on a new page, it stretches the whole content of the conclusion page s.t. it fills up the whole page. This leads to the ugly thing that the spacing between the lines and paragraphs becomes huge.

I googled a bit, but didn't found any option to avoid this.

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12918/can-we-have-a-ruling-on-latex-on-stackoverflow on the appropriateness of latex questions on SO.

Comment: Yes. Everything that is not programming related does not belong, so anything that *does* belong must be programming related.

Comment: Sure, I was already wondering why there exists a tag "not-programming-related".

Comment: It is a hanger on from an earlier epic on the site. Some moderate rep users use it to draw the attention of higher rep users to questions that might need closing. I believe that this is discouraged, but can't provide a link.

Answer (score 21):

Add `\raggedbottom` to the latex preamble that will solve it.

Comment: This was pretty helpful! Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 13):

Not quite sure whether this will solve your problem, but try `\clearpage` instead of `\pagebreak` .

Comment: Sorry, tried it the wrong way. It fixed my problem (although I guess it's just a "hack")

Comment: Not a hack. \clearpage tells LaTeX that you explicitly want this page terminated early. \pagebreak assumes you want balanced pages (in twopage mode), instead.

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
\vfill\clearpage
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe I was able to fix a similar problem with the [`multicol` package](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=multicol), which provides a rather more powerful multi-column environment that the one built into the standard classes.

---

I just thought: are you using `\raggedbottom`? That would be worth a shot before bringing in a new package.

Comment: No I'm not using \raggedbottom

Comment: Just another question, without having to open a new post. Do you have some info on how to correctly include urls in a bib db file?? With MISC?? Are there any other options?

Comment: There are several issues with URLs, but I think that most of them have already been addressed on SO. Try this search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[latex]+url I'm not sure what special issues you'll face in a bibliography.

Comment: \raggedbottom isn't always appropriate for the whole document; twopage spreads are balanced (i.e., end at the same vertical position) for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the `\newpage` in this case ?